# method name part of same singleton class?

Tags: iphone, ios, singleton

I have a class, in that class I have set up a singleton patter and have a method, here is a short example of what it looks like.

```
#pragma mark Singleton Methods
+ (id)sharedManager {
    @synchronized(self) {
        if (sharedMyManager == nil)
            sharedMyManager = [[self alloc] init];
    }
    return sharedMyManager;
}
- (id)init {
    if (self = [super init]) {
//so some init stuff here
//...
}

-(void)savemethod {
//etc etc
}
```

I'm wondering if I am to call/initalize the singleton class to be used like so

```
//set up plist controller class as a singleton so that you dont loose cache numbers etc
    EnginePropertiesController *enginePC = [EnginePropertiesController sharedManager];
```

then later on in the same class where I have initialized the singleton I call the save method...

[enginePC saveMethod];

So what im wondering is saveMethod part of the same instance? I think it is because i am using the same initialization name enginePC.. but would like some clarification on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding you, you are correct that `saveMethod` would be called on the singleton instance. What you name a pointer has no bearing on what it points to.

Comment: cool.. I thought so but wanted to check to make sure my understanding was correct. I am currently doing some stuff with property lists and I am loosing the values that I save in my save method when I delete the app from multitasking which I am trying to find the reason for.. I thought maybe this was it and i was working in different instances some how.

Comment: Interesting. That may merit a new question, but are you trying to save to a `.plist` file that you created (i.e.: not your `app.plist`)?

Comment: Yes I have asked several questions trying to solve my plist issue.. :( each time I ask a new question the next evolves into the new problem..  Its just super weird... hopefully I will get to the bottom of it at some point :P
Yep question marked I had to wait another couple of minutes because it was answered so fast. :)